# AWS Cognito and AWS S3 integration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

Is it possible to restrict AWS S3 objects such that only users who authenticate via AWS Cognito gain access to the object? I haven't figured out a way to do this, but it seems obvious to me that this would be a use case.

I want to host a website via AWS S3 and restrict some objects (my pages) so that if a user were to go them directly they'd get a permission denied error. If the user was authenticated via AWS Cognito tho the object should be available.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Deny access to objects in the secured directory.",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::domain.com/secured/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Only allowed authenticated users access to a specific bucket.",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::x:role/Cognito_Domain_IdP_Auth_Role"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::domain.com/secured/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Read access for web hosting.",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::domain.com/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have you looked here? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_cognito-bucket.html

Comment: I have tried everything trying to get this to work to no avail. I have created a custom IdP in AWS Cognito, which created two roles - one for unauth and one for auth, however I cannot configure an S3 bucket using these roles. I'm genuinely at a total loss.

Comment: Could you tell what are your current S3 permissions ? Maybe it's getting accessed because of other allowed ways.

Comment: Thanks Deepthi, I just posted my S3 bucket policy. I think this works. Now I just need to figure out how to login using a Cognito Identity Pool. I can login with a User Pool, is it different?

Comment: Do you want a pure web app with static content or are you willing to have some backend (e. g. lambda). Depends on the answer you may have different options

Comment: What I want is to have some content that's restricted ... like an account.html page that makes use of an AWS API Gateway endpoint (which is also protected). It just feels more polished for the user to get an error message indicating he/she doesn't have access to the account.html page if he/she attempts to go there directly w/o logging in first. I could even redirect the user to a login page if I get a 403 error.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a role to your users authenticated via cognito and then allow them certain actions.

**Creating Roles for Role Mapping**

It is important to add the appropriate trust policy for each role so that it can only be assumed by Amazon Cognito for authenticated users in your identity pool. Here is an example of such a trust policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "us-east-1:12345678-dead-beef-cafe-123456790ab"
        },
        "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "authenticated"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Granting Pass Role Permission**

To allow an IAM user to set roles with permissions in excess of the user's existing permissions on an identity pool, you grant that user iam:PassRole permission to pass the role to the set-identity-pool-roles API.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/myS3WriteAccessRole"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

More Info here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/role-based-access-control.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve that
But for that you can not achieve it directly configuring through the console

> →First you need to create policy with limited access of Cognito and S3 bucket
>
> →Create a role attaching them
>
> →Assign them to your EC2 or Lambda
>
> →Authenticate the user in your application using Cognito
>
> →Using that you can have a signed URL for S3 object and retrieve them

This may help you